# como subir un proyecto de laravel a producción?

Tags: laravel-5, hosting

Tengo una consulta cuando instalo el `laravel` pesa regular y mientras voy avanzando con el proyecto pesa un poco mas pero veo que no utilizo todo lo que `laravel` se instala al principio, mi pregunta es ¿si al poner en producción tiene que subir con todo eso, o hay forma de solo subir lo que se usa en el proyecto?Gracias.

Comment: Podes no subir los archivos que generan los assets, como toda la carpeta `node_modules`, pero el resto es probable que lo tengas que subir todo.

Comment: lo recomendado seria tener tu carpeta vendor completa en caso de que en un futuro comiences a utilizar mas funcionalidades de laravel así no te arias lió mas adelante de que seria lo que deberías subir.

Answer (score 1):

Tu directorio `vendor` qué utiliza *composer* para bajar las dependencias que utiliza tu aplicación **PHP Laravel** siempre debería de estar con lo que le asigne composer al ejecutar el comando `composer install`. Al igual qué en proyectos **JavaScript** sucede con *node_modules* al ejecutar el comando `npm install` o *bower_component* al ejecutar el comando `bower install`..

En caso de borrar cualquier directorio de tu `vendor` podrías poner en un posible mal funcionamiento tu aplicación, ya qué es muy probable que tú directamente no utilices la dependencia, pero otra dependencia si la utilice...